# Mgmt Studio save results as issue

Tags: sql, grid

I have a SQL query that returns 1 column.  I run it in SQL Server Management Studio 2008R2.
I use File\Save Grid Results and create a .TXT file.

My problem is the first record of the file has 3 bytes inserted in front of the data.  They three bytes are x'EFBBBF'.  This causes problem when I use the file in another process.

I get the same thing wheter I save as .TXT or as .CSV.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found it.

1. **Save Results As...**
2. Choose a folder
3. Enter a file name
4. **Save** button now has a dropdown arrow to the right
5. Click on dropdown arrow and select **Save with Encoding...**
6. Select **ANSI**
7. Click **OK**

The ANSI-encoded file will not contain a UTF-8 BOM.

Comment: Great spot!  I was opening the file in Notepad++ and changing the encoding manually to ANSI.

Answer (score 1):

kuru kuru na is on the right track, those bytes are the UTF-8 BOM.  I haven't found any settings to change the file encoding that Management Studio uses for saving results.  I just use Vim to remove the BOM after saving the file.  Your favorite text editor may have a similar option, or you could use a tool like iconv if you need to remove the mark or re-encode the file in a script.

Comment: I'll add:  it's a little silly that SSMS saves result files in an encoding (UTF-8 w/ BOM) that BULK INSERT doesn't understand.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's called a "bom" (byte order mark) signature, which has something to do with telling whatever reads your file that it contains utf characters.  I suspect it might be in your SMSS settings somewhere.  But at least this is a place to start.

Comment: Went through all the SMSS setting I could find.  Nothing about save format.  Instead of UTF-8 I need plain MS-DOS text.